# Calling .getBackground() in universal onClick method

Tags: android, button, onclick

I want to include many buttons in my app, which can play a sound by clicking, so I included an OnClick event.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();

    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.whisteling_bird:
            stopandPlay(R.raw.whisteling_bird, mediaPlayer);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

But now I have the following problem:
I also want to change the Alpha value of the button by using

```
.getBackground().setAlpha(64);
```

But what do I have to write before .getBackground()?
I don´t want to write this

```
final Button whisteling_bird = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.whisteling_bird);
whisteling_bird.setOnClickListener(this);

whisteling_bird.getBackground().setAlpha(64);
```

for every single button. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onClick(), below id line,
put `view.getBackground().setAlpha(64);`
it will set every clicked view's alpha to 64. But you will also need to reset it somewhere for safety.